# How do you display data from a second model in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make a pedigree website for dogs, and I'm trying to figure out how to show data on the parents, offspring, etc. on the details page of a dog.

```
@model DogPedigree.Entities.Dog

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Dog</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AKCRegNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AKCRegNumber)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sex)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sex)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.breed)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.breed)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.birthday)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.birthday)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sirenumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sirenumber)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.damnumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.damnumber)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.AKCRegNumber }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

So the model.AKCRegNumber is my primary key, and the sirenumber is the AKCRegNumber for the father and the damnumber is the AKCRegNumber for the mother. Any tips on how to pull some data from the parents row, like maybe displaying the name as a link to the details page for the parent? Thanks

Comment: Your dog class should have navigation properties that go 1-many from parent to child. You should be able to populate these values in your query so that they are made available to the view model.

Comment: In short, if you need multiple models, make a large model that has all the other models as properties. In this case, as described by @TravisJ, create a model that holds references to all the child nodes you'll need in the view.

Comment: Okay, so to reiterate what you're saying to make sure I'm understanding, a potential solution would be to make a Pedigree class that is a collection of all the Dog objects that I want to display and just have a separate view for Pedigree.

Comment: Yes to a Pedigree class. Though really that's just a Dog class (or maybe a derived class of Dog if Dam and Sire are not part of Dog) that you include the Sire and Dam navigation properties, and those in turn also get included so you can go up the family tree as far as you need. Now you're looking at more of a treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a model that is wider in scope:

```
using DogPedigree.Entities

public class DogModel
{
    public Dog CurrentDog { get; set; }
    public Dog FatherDog { get; set; }
    public Dog MotherDog { get; set; }
    // other properties you need...
}
```

Fill your DogModel with whatever data you need (e.g. from the database) before you send it to the View.

You can also add a property for `Title` to this model...

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

...instead of setting and retrieving from ViewBag.

In short: create the model as expansive as you need it, fill it with relevant data, then pass to the View.

Comment: Okay I see how that works, but a problem I was running into was how to pass the relevant model info to the view. My solution was to add a Pedigree class to my DogController, I'll put the code into my own answer. I was wondering if it was followed best MVC practices, since I did not make a new model I just added Linq queries to pull the info from the DogsModel.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: create a class that will be responsible for filling the models that you use - something like a 'Data Layer' of sorts. Your controller will get quite large at this rate. So if your new `DataLayer` class has a method of `GetPedigree(int id)`, you can call it from your Controller like so: `new DataLayer().GetPedigree(5)` (or perhaps create an instance of it, and use that). You'll be thankful that you separated these concerns early up.

Answer (score 0):

So I added a new method to my DogsController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Pedigree(int id)
    {
        var dog = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        var dam = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == dog.Dam);
        var sire = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == dog.Sire);
        var damDam = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == dam.Dam);
        var damSire = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == dam.Sire);
        var sireDam = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == sire.Dam);
        var sireSire = await _context.Dogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == sire.Sire);
        Dogs[] dogs = new Dogs[7] { dog, dam, sire, damDam, damSire, sireDam, sireSire };
        return View(dogs.ToList());
    }
```

And it works great. I was wondering if this was in line with MVC best practices?

Comment: Considering, per your question, you want links between the dogs then the answer @cyrotello provided is more inline than an array. If you were considering creating links between dogs based on array position then keep in mind this is not easily readable (i.e. how is one to know dogs[1] is the dam) without looking how the array is constructed. Now your model is implementation specific. The idea behind a model is to provide the least amount of information necessary to easily create and maintain the view.

Comment: Agreeing with @hubsonbropa; better to have your Model as a separate class, which can be composed of whatever fields/properties you need: list(s) of dogs, plus other auxiliary properties, as needed. (I'd also use a `List<Dog>`, rather than an array.)